# How to print javascript array with Model list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

with asp .net mvc5, how to recover the model in javascript?
here are my codes

**Ctrl:**

```
public ActionResult Test() {

    var data = List<string>() {
        "test",
        "essai"
    };

    return View(data); 
}
```

**View:**

```
@model ...

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/Parametre/DatePublication.js"></script>
}
```

**Partial Js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(@Model);
});
```

The @Model in partial Js is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in **Razor**, because in **Razor** every content using a `@` block is automatically **HTML** encoded by Razor.

The solution is to iterate your list and create a `javascript` array.

```
var myArray = [];
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @:myArray.push('@item');
}
console.log(myArray);
```

Inside the `@foreach` block, you need to mark the `markup` or `Javascript` using `@:` markup or `<text>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

`Model` will work only in razor views which can execute server code. If you want this as a javascript array in an external javascript file, you may read it to a js array variable inside a razor view and use it later in other scripts

```
 <script>
     var myArray = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
     console.log(myArray);
 </script>
 <script src="ExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

You can access myArray in `ExternalJsFile.js` now.

Passing data via simple global variables are not a great idea. They are prone to get overwritten.(What if some thirdparty plugin script you load is also using the same variable name ? ) So you should consider namespacing your data to be safe.

For example,

```
 <script>
     var myApp = myApp || {};  
     myApp.pageData = myApp.pageData || {};
     myApp.pageData.model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
 </script>
 <script src="ExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

Now in the externalJs file, you can access it like `console.log(myApp.pageData.model)`